# Ontograf - How to use it in an independent application?

Tags: java, semantic-web, protege

I want to use **OntoGraf** plugin of Protégé 2000, which is used to draw ontologies graphs, in another application to be able to use independently from Protégé.

Is it possible technically? if so, is there any documentation that can show how OntoGraf works?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OntoGraph is only a Protégé plugin. Please refer to [OntoGraph Wiki](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/OntoGraf):

> Protege Desktop plug-in that allows visual, interactive navigation of the relationships in OWL ontologies.

However there are other tools that you can use to visualize that are independent. For example, [OWLGrEd](http://owlgred.lumii.lv/) just needs an OWL or RDF file and it can visualize it. I am sure there are more flexible ones out there.

If your aim is to use it in your own program, there are tools such as [GLOW](http://www.glowvis.org/Main_Page).

Comment: Thanks for the information ! Can i integrate OWLGrEd in my own java application ?

Comment: I revised my answer. But Glow is just one of the tools.

Comment: @Calips unless your application is replicating the environment that these plugins need, the answer is no. Some of them, however, are just libraries, so it would be easy to use them from any application. In Ontograf case, you can use the source code in the GitHub repositories to see what's required to integrate it.